# SELECT n-th row WHERE field = x value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
format(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT * FROM `datab` WHERE License = %s", searchPlate);
```

Querying with this format will give me all the rows with this result, but what i'm trying to do is take for ex. the third or fifth or even tenth row that has this result, not all of the rows. How can i do this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Also in what order do you want the 3rd or 4th row? Because without an order by you can't expect a deterministic result. Look at TOP in SQL-Server and LIMIT in MySQL. Then use either max or min on the variable you order by.

Comment: It's query'd from a game script. It's a PAWN script for SA-MP that queries the database for specific results and returns them for further use, not a specific database management program.

Comment: @Dan It should be ordered by the first column, which is basically a auto-increment ID column.

Comment: The back-sticks around the table name seem to suggest that you are using MySql.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in MySQL:

```
format(sql, sizeof(sql), "SELECT * FROM `datab` WHERE License = %s ORDER BY IDColumnNameGoesHere LIMIT %d, 1", searchPlate, MyDesiredRowInteger);
```

Some points:

- `%d` might not be right, use the correct symbol for an integer.
- You are most definitely using a specific RDBMS, you must look into the documentation and find out. SQL is a standard, MySQL ans SQL-Server etc are implementations of that standard. You must find out which implementation you are using.
- Sticking variables into strings like you have done leaves you very vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). You should always parameterize your queries.
- [LIMIT is specific to MySQL](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm) if you are using a different RDBMS you will have to go another route. For example SQL-Server you can use TOP, but as this only has one parameter you will need to use min or max in addition to only get the one record you desire.